# Missing input form request data

Tags: html, laravel, forms

When I get `dd($request->all())`

```
<form id="change_application_status" action="{{route('change_application_status')}}" method="post">
                                                  
<input type="hidden" name="application_id" value="{{$withdraw_history->id}}"> 
                                                     
<label for="status">Status:</label>     
<select name="status" class="form-control bb">
<option value="Pending">Pending</option>
<option value="Reject">Reject</option>
<option value="Approved">Approved</option>
</select>
 @csrf
<label for="details">Remarks:</label>
<textarea name="datails" rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" placeholder="Write here datails about transaction ....">
</textarea>
                                                
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Result

```
array:2 [▼
  "application_id" => "4"
  "_token" => "8yh2qaLnwAj5gBaKqXsiXNpshxKaNOeQi7As6nXu"
]
```

Comment: please share the controller method where you are doing dd of all ...